# Why no "? super X" in JPA API Path.get(MapAttribute) and Path.get(PluralAttribute) parameter?

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

This is a design question about the [JPA API for Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/?javax/persistence/criteria/Path.html).

(I'm not trying to solve a problem or looking for a workaround, just asking a question about why the API was designed a certain way.)

The API has these methods:

1. `<Y> Path<Y> Path.get(SingularAttribute<? super X, Y> attribute)`
2. `<E, C extends Collection<E>>
   Expression<C> Path.get(PluralAttribute<X, C, E> attribute)`
3. `<K, V, M extends Map<K,V>>
   Expression<M> Path.get(MapAttribute<X, K, V> attribute)`

My question is how come method #1 accepts an attribute with generic type `<? super X, ...>`, but methods #2 and #3 only accept an attribute with generic type `<X, ...>` ?

It seems like the same reasoning should apply in all three cases: that is, the attribute can originate from (i.e., correspond to a property declared in) class `X` or any superclass of `X`.

Yet in #2, and #3, the attribute is only allowed to originate from class `X`.

Is this is a design oversight in the JPA specification, or is there some underlying reason for the difference that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I wonder why it's `? super X` in case of the singular attribute.

Comment: because the API is incorrect, and the JPA "expert group" haven't bothered correcting it, despite being told about it https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/108

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. This is a spec bug.

Thanks to @DN1 who pointed out the [spec issue](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/108) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097729/why-no-super-x-in-jpa-api-path-getmapattribute-and-path-getpluralattribut?noredirect=1#comment85203200_49097729).